# Estimate CV error of R's lda using the package cvTools

Tags: r

I'm trying to use the package `cvTools` to estimate the classification error of a LDA fit. I've used cvTools successfully in the past with other models, but with LDA it doesn't work as expected.

```
data <- rbind(data.frame(cls='A', x=rnorm(10, mean=5)),
              data.frame(cls='B', x=rnorm(10, mean=10)))
cv.fit <- cvFit(
    lda,
    formula=cls ~ x,
    data=data,
    cost=function(true, pred) { 
        mean(true != pred)
    },
    K=10
)
```

It seems cvTools uses the generic `predict` model function internally. `predict.lda` doesn't return a simple vector of class labels, but rather a list with attributes `class`, `posterior` and `x`.
If I set a debug breakpoint in the cost function I see that `true` is a vector of class labels but `pred` is said list converted to a vector.
So my question is how I can still use cvTools with LDA.

My first idea was to provide a new predict method by subclassing `lda` in the hope that cvTools will then call my predict function which returns a vector of class labels:

```
lda.fit <- lda(cls ~ x, data)

class(lda.fit) <- c('ldaCV', class(lda.fit))
predict.ldaCV <- function(m, newdata) {
    MASS:::predict.lda(m, newdata)$class
}

cv.fit <- cvFit(
    lda.fit,
    data=data,
    y=data$cls,
    cost=function(true, pred) { 
        mean(true != pred)
    },
    K=10
)
```

Nothing changes however. `pred` is still the same messed up list.

Comment: I'm having a hard time finding the exact question here. Can you make it more clear what the problem is and what the desired result is?

Comment: Normally the function `cvFit` fits a model using cross validation and reports the estimated error. When using `lda` as the model this doesn't work correctly. It seems that the reason is that the `predict` function, which is often used in R to use a fitted model to predict the response for new data, doesn't follow the convention that `predict(fitted.model, newdata)` returns a vector of responses. `predict.lda` returns a list, where the `class` attribute of this list is the response. `cvFit` can't handle this list-resonse. My question is how to use cvTools with lda.